# iOS 8 AutoLayout + UIScrollView: Preview OK, Build UIScrollView empty

Tags: uiscrollview, ios8, autolayout

I have a weird problem: I use Autolayout for a UIScrollView with child views, and when I show the Preview everything looks fine:

[image]

But when I build the app the content is not shown correctly, seems to be an content size issue.

[image]

I pinned all of the child views correctly, didn't set any content size (as should be with autolayout scrollviews), but I can't get the scrollview work with correct content size.

Anyone that can help me on that?

Thanks!